# Get current group name in a Pandas data frame plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a data frame like that (it's just the head) :

```
                       Timestamp Function_code  Node_id  Delta
0     2000-01-01 10:39:51.790683      Tx_PDO_2       54  551.0
1     2000-01-01 10:39:51.791650      Tx_PDO_2       54  601.0
2     2000-01-01 10:39:51.792564      Tx_PDO_3       54  545.0
3     2000-01-01 10:39:51.793511      Tx_PDO_3       54  564.0
```

There are only two types of `Function_code` : `Tx_PDO_2` and `Tx_PDO_3`

I plot in two windows, a graph with `Timestamp` on the x-axis and `Delta` on the y-axis. One for `Tx_PDO_2` and the other for `Tx_PDO_3` :

```
delta_rx_tx_df.groupby("Function_code").plot(x="Timestamp", y="Delta", )
```

Now, I want to know which window corresponds to which `Function_code`

I tried to use `title=delta_rx_tx_df.groupby("Function_code").groups` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but for starters, you can assign the titles to the plots after they are created:

```
plots = delta_rx_tx_df.groupby("Function_code").plot(x="Timestamp", y="Delta")
plots.reset_index()\
     .apply(lambda x: x[0].set_title(x['Function_code']), axis=1)
```

Comment: It works, but i'm curious for the "better way"/

Comment: Define "better."

Comment: You start your answer by _"There may be a better way"_ but in deed I think this is the best way for what I wand to do.

Comment: I see what you mean :) Yes, there *may* be a one-line solution, that's what I meant by a "better way."